# Is it always relevant to target RESTful design for a public web service/API?

Tags: web-services, rest, asp.net-web-api, architecture, restful-architecture

No doubt that RESTful is buzz word and seems to be a cleaver design pattern in many cases.

Struggling to apply it to my own web APIs (existing and upcoming) I finally wonder if it is relevant for what I do (if we forget the fact that it is in some RFC's we try to respond to ;)).

First of all I'm mostly dealing with dynamic data determined at least 3 parameters, possibly up to 10.

Think for instance about a web API performing sound effects and format conversion (equalize, echo, volume, speed, ...). You need send it your credentials, an undeterminated set of effect name and settings  and the sound to equalize.

The url could be something like effectMaker/echo/10pct/equalizer/20kHz/-10pct/output-rate/192kbps/

- some parameters in http header (response format for instance)
- the sound in body.

So, functions are defined by http methods + url root and parameters are in body, url tail and header. Does not seems very convenient, neither for me nor developers discovering my API.

Besides that, the caching ability does not make sens as most of my users request are unique.

So, I'm asking you if I'm wrong thinking that I should try to integrate what makes sens in the REST "philosophy" (stateless, discoverable, ...) for my use, but just drop some part of it that are pointless (cacheable) or makes API odd? For instance should I really stick to HTTP verbs when you push some data in the body and expect to get converted data in response?

To me it seems that RESTFull design makes sens when you manage / consume online databases items accessible through a quite simple path. When your API creates/transforms data for a likely unique usage it seems inconvenient. When you have a dozen of parameters accepting various values, it seems painfull.

However, soap and XML-RPC standards are quite ugly in my opinion...

So is it bad to make RESTlike or AsRESTasRelevant design associated with json parameters/response when it seems wiser?

Any advice of a standard to follow in my case?

Cheers,

Vincent

Answer (score 0):

REST is not a philosophy. It's an architectural style - a way of designing systems to meet certain [goals](http://whatisrest.com/rest_architectural_goals/index). If those goals aren't yours, then REST is a bad idea. If they are, then REST is a good idea. We don't know what your goals are, so we have no idea if REST is a good fit for you.

This next bit doesn't really have to do with REST, it's more generic web API design,

Don't use the URL to contain processing instructions. As you say, that's totally unwieldy for non-trivial systems. Either support [Multipart](https://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/media-types.xhtml#multipart) requests that contain the processing instructions in one part and the audio file in another part, or treat the file upload and the processing instructions as two separate requests. You could even support both.

Just spitballing, if I were trying to design this as a RESTish API, I might start near

```
POST /audio-files

request:
Content-type: audio/midi
<audio file>

response:
201 Created
Location: http://example.com/audio-files/12
```

-

```
POST /audio-files

request:
Content-type: multipart/mixed; boundary="simple boundary"
--simple boundary
Content-type: application/json; charset=us-ascii
{
   "echo": "true",
   ...
}
--simple boundary
Content-type: audio/midi; charset=us-ascii
<audio file>
--simple boundary--

response:
200 Ok
Link: <http://example.com/audio-files/12>; rel="audio-file"
<altered-audio-file>
```

-

```
POST /altered-audio-files

request:
Content-type: application/json; charset=us-ascii
{
    "audio-file": "http://example.com/audio-files/12"
    "echo": "true",
    ...
}

response:
200 Ok
<altered-audio-file>
```

This treats the audio file and altered audio files as resources. That allows you to save on wire time by holding onto uploaded audio files when somebody wants to run eight transformations on the same file, and gives you the option to hold onto altered audio files if you later choose to do so. If you want to track requests, you could easily do that by adding a third endpoint, maybe `/audio-requests`.